# RUN systemctl start newrelic-infra,error :Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted

Tags: docker, centos, newrelic, systemctl

**RUN systemctl start newrelic-infra**(while building docker file) on **cent os 7**

We obtain the following error message:

```
Step 28/28 : RUN systemctl  start newrelic-infra
 ---> Running in f9a82da02f00
**Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted**
The command '/bin/sh -c systemctl  start newrelic-infra' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Even after including these steps in docker file,

[image: docker file]

I am getting the same error. How do we resolve it

Answer (score 0):

The mounted volume may work during runtime of the container but not during build.

In many cases you do not need to run systemd in container anyway as you can run "systemctl" commands with the [docker-systemctl-replacement](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement) scripts.